PROGRESS 4GL - How to read JSON file and store it into temp table?
I am new to progress 4GL and want to know how to write a query which parse below json file and store it into temp table.
{
"sdion": "VSSDG",
"Count": 1,
"documentSummary": [
    {
        "ddoid": "SSFG11GFG",
        "submiss": "SSFG11GFG"
    }
]
}


Can I get sample query for this?

Unless that's just a sample of the data that really doesnt look like something to store in a temp-table. A temp-table would be a better fit for a repetitive dataset (where one repetition equals one record in the temp-table).
